# Suggestion to merge shopping and price. Are they on-topic at all?

Tags: feature-request, tagging

[shopping](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping) and [price](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/price) are very related, don't have wikis.

Comment: Is this two questions? 1) Are shopping and price questions on topic? And 2) If they're on topic, should they be merged?

Comment: As for the on-topic portion of this question: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/276/do-we-go-shopping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reviewing a good sample of the questions in each tag, I don't think these two tags should be merged. Most of the (non-closed) [shopping](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping) questions are about what to look for, while the [price](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/price) questions are specifically about prices.